# Is it possible to grep a string and print 200 lines from where the string appears

Tags: grep

I want to navigate through a log which is of 10000 lines and after using grep on particular string I want 200-300 lines  printed when that string first appears. is it possible

Comment: Yes. Read `man grep`. See `-A -B -C` options.

Answer (score 0):

With `awk` this is trivial:

```
$ awk -v cnt=200 '/ur_regex/ {seen=1} seen && cnt{print; cnt--}' your_file
```

Or with grep:

```
$ grep -A 200 'ur_regex' file
```

Comment: You probably want `-m 1` on your `grep` for just the first match...